# PyDev unresolved import while loading another module within package

Tags: python, eclipse, import, module, pydev

I've got the application structure like:

```
app:
 package:
  module1
  module2
```

From the module2 I try to load the class in module1 like that:

```
from module1 import classname
```

It works for Python 3.3, but does not for Eclipse PyDev. It has highlighted my import line saying:

```
Unresolved import: classname
```

Of course when I've moved out my module2 outside the package I could import the module1 classname using that import:

```
from package.module1 import classname
```

It worked both for Eclipse and Python console interpreter, however that's not the solution.

How do I make Eclipse happy about the Unresolved import? Thanks